# Using MCU as a power switch to PC -- connecting the thing correctly

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, 5v, 3.3v

My LED strip projects are done and completed succesfully for now and I am back with a question regarding powering MCU when using it as a remote PC switch.

So what I have so far: a Raspbi Pico W which is connected to 5vsb (from internal USB pins) on my pc motherboard to sustain it's power even when the pc is turned off. This is confirmed working and Pico stays powered on when I power off my PC.

Now what I still need is to be able to drive power switch pins on the motherboard using the Pico. I have seen a few similar projects using ESP's around the interwebs but since I do not fully understand electronics yet I though it would be better to ask:

Since the Pico is powered by 5vsb from the psu (motherboard, stand by USB power from internal USB pins), and the power switch has 3v3, that means they are on separate circuits (?) and "just connecting" the power pins to the GPIO would presumably be bad.

https://github.com/Erriez/ESPHomePCPowerControlHomeAssistant

The linked setup is pretty much what I had in mind except for the resistors and transistor, which I didn't think about before I came up with the idea. Also I would like to read pc state from maybe the power LED pins.

Question is: what would be the safest and best practice way of doing this kind of connection? And can someone walk me through what exactly are the transistors and resistors doing in Erriez's build?

Also, as I seem to get more and more interested in these IoT tinkerings which usually include a bit of electrical know how, can someone suggest a good "low voltage electrical engineering for dummies" -materials I should read to familiarize myself with the subject?

Edit1:

I thought I'd mention that I was thinking of simplifying things by using maybe an SSR to short the power pins, but I still need to read the state of the PC, maybe from power led, which was also 3v3 if I remember correctly.

Edit2:

Also I was thinking if anything would change if I found a standby 3v3 and powered the pico from that since it accepts 3,3v as power input.

Comment: The power supply needs its PS_ON input pulled low to switch it on, that's what the power switch normally does and it's what the transistor in that circuit does too. As it's usually pulled up to standby voltage you shouldn't try to drive it high. The PSU also provides a PWR_OK output you can use to see if it's switched on and ready.

Comment: @Finbarr No that's not how it works at all. The pushbutton does not connect to ATX supply PS_ON. Pushbutton connects to motherboard logic, and motherboard logic will then drive PS_ON low until someone wants to turn the PC off and then motherboard logic releases PS_ON to float high.

Comment: Have you considered turning on the PC using [Wake-on-LAN](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) instead?

Comment: @marcelm I have yes, but I would really like to go down the physical route. Also, I'm 99% sure my hardware doesn't support wireless WoL, which I would need since I'm unable to use wired network at this time. I could be wrong on the wireless WoL tho...

Comment: @marcelm continues: I want to do it the physical way as a learning experience. I don't really care if I ruin the resale value of my components by modding them. It's all good fun  also I'm in SE by trade, I like to include actual handy work in my personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no standard dictating how the power button is wired in an ATX system, so for full compatibility you'll need to use some sort of relay for that function.  this could be a mosfet based solid-state relay or a reed switch relay.  a phototransitor opto-isolator may also work if you can measure, or guess, the correct polarity.

Howevwer in practice the power button seems to always have one lead grounded and the other pulled up to some logic level (like 5V or 3.3V) though a faily large resistance (like 10K), so any microcontroller than has or can fake an open drain output capable of 5V can be used to signal the power button input.

For a 5V Arduino this means configuring the pin as an input while idle and and as a low output when active. You may need to guess (or measure) which of the power pins needs the signal, or you could use 2 GPIO pins and signal on both pins at the same time, (one of the outputs will be grounding a ground - no harm no foul)

with the pi pico you're not so lucky, because the GPIO is 3.3V, and the motherboard circuit that's sensing the power button is powered from 5V (because that's all that is available)

Comment: So even tho I measure 3.3v for the power pins, I need 5v logic. I have a few bi directional level shifters lying around, would it be possible to level shift the 3.3v to 5v and call it profit?

Comment: if you measure 3.3v  you should be fine connecting to 3.3v GPIO.  I was trying to cover the general case rather than a single case in my answer. also I ran out of steam and left it unfinished  80-20 rule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't really know what is the electrical specification for your or any other motherboard.

You can measure how your motherboard works and we can make assumptions how they might work in general, but we can never assume how to interface them and if it will always work, and even if it des not work, will it be OK or will there be damage.

So first of all, the power button. Look at motherboard manual. The manual says to connect a pushbutton diretly between two pins. Typically, one of the pins is ground, and the other pin is the input signal, which must be grounded via the button when it is pushed. Typically that's all you know, but what is the idle voltage level of the signal input, and what is the amount of current flowing when button is pushed, they are both not standardized. Modern motherboard might simply have a resistor to 3.3V and current might be less than 1mA.

The problem is, there is no guarantee about this, as there is even no guarantee if the manual mentions which pin is ground and which pin is signal. It could also be some other arrangement. So in theory you could simply connect the signal pin to your MCU directly, in practice the safest option is to emulate the pushbutton with a relay.

Same with the LED pins if you want to detect when the PC is on. The motherboard manual simply says which is the LED positive pin and which is the LED negative pin, and those will be directly connected to power LED of the PC case. You don't get any info about what circuitry there is to drive the LED.

The power LED pins might just be ground for cathode and +5V via a fixed value resistor for anode. The resistor could be on the cathode side instead of anode side. The voltage could be 3.3V instead of 5V. The current might be anyone's guess. The LED could even be driven with PWM to have some brightness control, so it might be pulsed high currents instead of steady DC. PWM could be applied on the anode or cathode side. LED might blink in sleep mode. In theory anything is possible, so what best looks like a LED to a motherboard is an opto-isolator and the isolator output can connect to your MCU.

Comment: So I wasn't far off in thinking of using a solid state relay to emulate the power button? I didn't think about using an opto-isolator from power LED pins to MCU. Could I also use opto-isolator as a switch emulator?

Comment: Depends on opto-isolator and button current. I once measured that a certain motherboard reset button was in the order of 60-80mA, which was unreasonable really. And typical opto-isolator must be connected with correct polarity to replace the switch.